# How to select multiple tables when using Access 2013 linked table ODBC

Tags: microsoft-access

Would anyone know how to select multiple tables when linking to an ODBC connection in MS Access 2013?

I used to be able to hold down the shift key and skip lines that would automatically highlight and be selected.  The only option with 2013 seems to be selecting one table at time (I only have 3,188 tables I am trying to select  of 7,520 ).

Comment: This sounds like it's probably a better question for Superuser than Stackoverflow, since it doesn't have anything directly to do with programming. As a general rule, if a question is about a change in keybindings between two versions of a piece of software, it doesn't need a programmer to answer it.

Comment: How many versions back are you talking about? I just tried in Access 2010 and [Shift-Click] didn't work as (I think) you described. I could select more than one table/view, but only one click at a time.

Comment: We figured out it is the "range" option that did not work.  You can still click one table at time but not a range.

Comment: When you link to multiple tables, you can select the tables by Ctrl + Left Click. The other option would be to use a query that already selects off your two tables then bring in the query. Does not work well on tables with lots of rows, or tables that require a full table scan.